# stop deletion of job from quartz scheduler

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Hello I am using quartz scheduler for my application. I am running a job which is fired only once. Up to that everything is fine. But after job fired it is automatically deleted from the scheduler. How to stop that? I want to delete the job from user interface. Can any one help me?

Comment: @swapnil It's grammar not grammer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Make the job durable by setting the durability to true in your JobDetail.
If Using JobBuilder, call storeDurably.
http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/JobBuilder.html#storeDurably()